# How to Bind list box ItemsSource with array from external resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am currently using List box ItemsSource to bind the values 
from x:array like this:

```
     <x:Array x:Key="SampleImages" Type="{x:Type BitmapImage}">
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/a.png" />
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/b.jpg" />
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/c.jpg" />
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/d.jpg" />
     </x:Array>
```

Then using it in the same xaml page as

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource SampleImages}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Instead of defining the images in the array, 
I would like to use the array to get the images from another resource dictionary (SampleImages.xaml; so it is easier to change the images later if need arises) defined as -

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/a.png" />
    <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/b.jpg" />
    <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/c.jpg" />
    <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/d.jpg" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How would you refer the SampleImages.xaml in x:Array ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the whole `Array` to your resource file. 
Reference it in your `app.xaml` to be available in the whole application.

**SampleImages.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <x:Array x:Key="SampleImages" Type="{x:Type BitmapImage}">
         <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/a.png" />
         <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/b.jpg" />
         <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/c.jpg" />
         <BitmapImage UriSource="www.google.com/d.jpg" />
  </x:Array>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="Project.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" >
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourResourceFolderIfAny/SampleImages.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Any other view:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource SampleImages}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```